# preserve initial whitespace in an html input

Tags: html, formatting

I've read several answers and none seen to work for my problem. 
I have an html input field, prepopulated value with "     .." (that's five spaces, two periods).

When this is presented on screen, the leading whitespace is squashed and the input shows "..      ".  I've set "white-space: pre;" in the style attribute but this does not solve the problem.

```
<input type="text" name="field_53_13" id="field_53_13" 
  class="h3270-input" 
  style="width:51.309998px; height: 15px; white-space: pre;" 
  value=".." maxlength="7" size="7">
```

Comment: &nbsp; will save you... see below...

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
<input type="text" name="field_53_13" id="field_53_13" 
  class="h3270-input" 
  style="width:51.309998px; height: 15px; white-space: pre;" 
  value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;.." maxlength="7" size="7">
```

None Breaking Space (&nbsp): https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/nbsp.htm